# When the spinner item is selected, I want the button text to be the selected spinner item. or can we just do it in string.xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

### MainActivity.java

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.Door_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    button.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Changing the text of button every time you must enter your code inside of this functions :

```
String spinner_text = "";
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View 
selectedItemView, 
int position, long id) {
        spinner_text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        yourButton.settext(spinner_text);//Set text to button

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // Set a default text on button
    }
});
```

Comment: The code was edited and the section to add text to the button was added. I hope your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Door_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int p3, long p4){
                button.setText(p1.getItemAtPosition(p3).toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> p1){}
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't.
[Spinner] Let it use door_array items.---
[Button] Let it use door2_array items.